# Caxis auto equivalent in OpenCV Python or Pillow?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

MATLAB has the function `caxis auto` which comes in handy for viewing images if they have a low contrast and are looking almost black.

In Matlab it works like this:

```
figure;imshow(I);caxis auto
```

I know  how to adjust the contrast in OpenCV Python, like:

```
 img = cv2.imread('someimage.jpg',0)
 equ = cv2.equalizeHist(img)

 #Showing image
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, this does is not the same implementation as `caxis auto` which changes the illuminuation adaptively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV does not use colormaps for displaying single channel images. In Matlab, `caxis` sets the colormap limits. In other words, if your image has values between 0.5 and 1.0, you can set the displayed color limits so that 0.5 is rendered *as if it were* 0.0, and scale that way. OpenCV just displays the image values as they are.

What that means is that if you want a different scaling for the values, you can just change them in the array that gets displayed.

With OpenCV, you can easily accomplish this scaling with [`cv2.normalize()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize) with the `normType=cv2.NORM_MINMAX`.

```
img = np.random.rand(500, 500, 3)*0.2
cv2.imshow('Low contrast image', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: Random image]

```
img_scaled = cv2.normalize(img, None, alpha=0.0, beta=1.0, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
cv2.imshow('Scaled colors for display', img_scaled)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: Scaled for display]

Note that this works for both grayscale and color images.

---

However, if you just have a grayscale image, another option is to display them with Matplotlib. MPL will automatically scale single channel images to the min/max display values.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = np.random.rand(500, 500)*0.2
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image: MPL scaling]

Note here I included the `cmap='gray'` argument because the default colormap for a single channel image is *Viridis*, and not grayscale. You can read more about Matplotlib colormaps [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). Generally, if you're looking for similar syntax to Matlab, Matplotlib has you covered---it was initially geared towards people coming to Python from Matlab, so it has similar functionality and syntax.

---

One last option is to just scale manually in numpy. If your image is an unsigned int type, you can do this simply by shifting the image to have it's lowest value as 0, and then multiply so that it's max value is the maximum of your datatype. Note that when you multiply your image will be converted to a float, so you'll need to recast it. For e.g., if you have a `uint16` image, the values range from 0 to 65535, so you could do:

```
img_scaled = img.copy() - np.min(img)
img_scaled = np.uint16(img_scaled*(65535/np.max(img)))
```

Or, if you'd like to do this automatically, you can grab the datatype information from the image (including the min and max values possible in a datatype) with [`np.iinfo()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html) to automatically scale and convert as necessary. Here's a function that will normalize any (signed or unsigned) integer or floating point image:

```
def normalize_minmax(img):
    """Scales an image into an interval [min, max] with the same datatype.

    If img.dtype is a float type, img is scaled into [0.0, 1.0].
    If img.dtype is an integer type, img is scaled into [dtype.min, dtype.max].
    If img.dtype is some other type, the original image is returned.
    """
    dtype = img.dtype
    if np.issubdtype(dtype, np.integer): # scale to [dtype.min, dtype.max]
        dtype_info = np.iinfo(img.dtype)
        img_scaled = img - np.min(img)
        scale = (dtype_info.max - dtype_info.min) / np.max(img_scaled)
        img_scaled = img_scaled * scale + dtype_info.min
        return np.round(img_scaled).astype(dtype)
    elif np.issubdtype(dtype, np.float):  # scale to [0, 1]
        img_scaled = img - np.min(img)
        img_scaled = img_scaled / np.max(img_scaled)
        return img_scaled.astype(dtype)
    return img
```

How it works is easy to describe. For the float image case, you simply shift it so that the lowest value is zero, and then divide by the max to get it between 0 and 1. Then just simply cast it back to the original type. For the integer datatypes, it takes a little more effort if you care to include signed integers. In this case the range extends to negative numbers as well. You start off the same by shifting the lowest value to zero. But then you need to scale so that the values span the entire range of the datatype (e.g. (datatype_max - datatype_min) / max(img)). So now your values will span from [0, datatype_max - datatype_min], so you need to add back the datatype_min to get to [datatype_min, datatype_max]. I also rounded the values instead of truncating before converting back to the original datatype.

Comment: Somehow the image is all black after the scaling with OpenCV (filled with zeros), do I need to convert it to a unique kind of data-type such as double? (Originally I have a uint16 grayscale image)

Comment: @Kev1n91 is it actually all zeros or does it just look black? I'm not sure if `normalize()` will work on `uint16` arrays or not (the docs don't mention a type, which means it should be applicable to all types, but a lot of OpenCV functions are limited to `uint8` and `float32`). You can convert the type first simply with `img = np.float32(img)` and it will scale to the min/max you set. For displaying, OpenCV requires that the image is `float32` with values between 0.0 and 1.0 (anything below is set to black, anything above to white) or `uint8`.

Comment: @Kev1n91 I added some code to do a manual scaling as well. I'll edit with a completely automated version for all dtypes to scale the min/max appropriately in a minute.

Comment: yeah it was all 0, i changed it to img.astypes(float) and it worked

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds normalize from OpenCV works with uint16 (I use this constantly), but if you do not specify the return type (dtype in documentation) it will take the one from the source... and if it 0-1 then you get an uint16 image with 0 and 1, you can specify the dtype as float and it works. I usually use 0-255 and type uint8 to display, but it is personal taste, float also works with imshow.

Comment: @Kev1n91 I added a function that will normalize any numpy array of integer or floating point type. It will scale to `[0, 1]` for float images and return the same floating point type (64-bit or 32-bit), and it will scale to `[dtype.min, dtype.max]` for any signed or unsigned integer datatype.

Comment: @Kev1n91 I think you were getting all zeros because you kept `alpha=0` and `beta=1` in your call. I used those because my image was a float type. For `uint16` images you'd want `alpha=0`, `beta=65535` so that it scales properly.